# Maintaining multiple docker images with common intermediate/final steps

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm in the situation where I have a bunch of images which come from different sources, but I need to apply the same steps to them. Basically it looks like this:

```
# dockerfile 1
FROM source1
RUN foo
```

```
# dockerfile 2
FROM source2
RUN bar
```

```
# dockerfile 3
FROM source3
RUN baz
```

Given these images, I need to apply some common steps, eg copy certificates, install commonly-used packages, set environment variables, etc.

```
ENV http_proxy http://proxy-server-address
ENV https_proxy http://proxy-server-address

ADD certs/* /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

RUN apt install something -y
RUN pip install something-else
# etc
```

Is there a good way to do this for all the images, without duplicating all the steps into each dockerfile? That would be a maintenance headache, since every time I change a step, I have to make sure I do it for all the files.

Comment: Can you make an image where you install the common software and then have source1, -2 and -3 base their images off of your image?

Comment: @HansKilian unfortunately, no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes

you can create a shared Dockerfile and take the source image as a build argument

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
# common steps
```

you can then call it for everyone of your builds with

`docker build ... --build-args BASE_IMAGE=<img_name>`

EDIT:

this means you call docker build twice for each image

once with the different dockerfiles foo, bar, baz and you should tag it as `foo_intermediate` etc

and then with the common dockerfile were the base image is `foo_intermediate` and tag it the way you need e.g. `foo`

Comment: This works, but I had to add a dummy ARG step before the FROM

Comment: yes, I added it now for completeness

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in this case is creating Dockerfile for base image where you put all the common steps.

In specific Dockerfiles you extend base image using `FROM base` and put image specific directives.

See sample base image Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/jmenga/todobackend-base/blob/master/Dockerfile) and specific image Dockerfile extending it [here](https://github.com/jmenga/todobackend/blob/master/docker/dev/Dockerfile).